# Work permit check at Indian airport after a flight from South Africa

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I would like to know whether when you fly from South Africa to India with a work permit, would this work permit checked at the Indian airport?

Comment: Welcome! Could you explain your question a little more please? You're flying from South Africa to India with an Indian work permit? And you're wondering if the authorities in India can check your work permit at the airport? Do I understand that right? It would help to explain why you're asking and what problem you're looking to solve.